# How to add special/non-word character in defined groups?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex which gives me separate groups of string.

old regex

```
const regex = /^(.*?)((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,5})?)(\D.*)?$/g;
```

new regex I wrote but not sure if it's right

```
const regex = /^(.*?)((?:([^\w\*])|(\d{1,3})(?:,\d{1,3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,5})?)(\D.*)?$/g
```

here is my regex explanation, which primarily I used to have numbers in `Group 2` but now that my input range is increasing I want `-` (non-word character) also to be recognized in it.

But IDK if it is possible to add `-` in the `Group 2`.

*PS: there won't be any different character other than `-` or `numbers`*
Input are as follows

```
const inputs= ["$200","$(200)%","100%","$-","$(52,000.5617)%","$30,000","45,444%"];
const regex = /^(.*?)((?:([^\w\*])|(\d{1,3})(?:,\d{1,3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,5})?)(\D.*)?$/g;
const text = inputs.match(regex);
let [_, preText = "", number = "", postText = ""] = text;
```

```
  1. ^ - start of string (.*?) - Group 1 (preText): any zero or more
    chars other than line break chars, as few as possible

    
  2. ((?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{1,3})*|\d+)(?:\.\d{1,5})?) - Group 2 (number): one
    to three digits followed with zero or more occurrences of a comma
    and one to three digits, or just one or more digits, and then an
    optional sequence of a . and one to five digits
    
  3. (\D.*)? - Group 3 (postText), optional: a non-digit char and then
    any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as
    possible $ - end of string.
```

Output:

1. this is the output I'm getting from my old regex

```
[_ = "$(52,000.5617)%", preText = "$", number = "52,000.5617", postText = ")%"]
```

2. this is my expected output

```
[_ = "$-", preText = "$", number = "-", postText = ""]
```

3. without `preText`

```
[_ = "45,444%", preText = "", number = "45,444", postText = "%"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the pattern a bit more specific and then allow / disallow what you want to capture.

You could use 3 optional capture groups that do not have overlapping matches, and use a negative lookahead do not match an empty string.

```
^(?!$)(\$?[^\d\n-]*)(-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,5})?|\d+)?)([^\d\n]*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?!$)` Assert not directly the end of the string
- `(\$?)` Capture **group 1**, match optional `$`
- `[^\d\n-]*` Optionally match chars other than a digit, newline or `-`
- `(` Capture **group 2**

  - `-?` Match optional `-`
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
    - `(?:,\d{3})*` Repeat 1+ times `,` and 3 digits
    - `(?:\.\d{1,5})?` Match optional `.` and 1-5 digits
    - `|` Or
    - `\d+` Match 1+ digits
  - `)?` Close the non capture group and make it optional
- `)` Close group 2
- `([^\d\n]*)` Capture **group 3**, match chars other than a digit or newline

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aMGbBa/1)

```js
const inputs = ["$200", "$(200)%", "100%", "$-", "$(52,000.5617)%", "$30,000", "45,444%"];
const regex = /^(?!$)(\$?[^\d\n-]*)(-?(?:\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{1,5})?|\d+)?)([^\d\n]*)$/;
inputs.forEach(s => {
  const m = s.match(regex);
  if (m) {
    let [_, preText = "", number = "", postText = ""] = m;
    console.log("input --> " + s);
    console.log("preText --> " + preText);
    console.log("number --> " + number);
    console.log("postText --> " + postText);
    console.log("------------------------------------");
  }
});
```

Comment: `[^\d\n%-]* Match optional chars other than a digit, newline, % or -` actually as per my examples I need to have the `)` and `)%` in my `postText`, this basically changes the groups overall.
My goal is to somehow include `-` which comes under Group 2 as per my requirement.

Comment: @yong I have updated the answer. If you also want the `(` in the preText, you can move that data also in group 1 like https://regex101.com/r/dBZE32/1

Comment: @SDP If the comma part should be optional, then it would be https://regex101.com/r/aMGbBa/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird thank you :), maybe i misread but `(?:,\d{3})* Repeat 1+ times , and 3 digits` you wrote here `*` instead of `+` so didn't notice it at first.

Comment: @SDP I have updated the answer with the `*` which repeats 0 or more times.